# как сделать так что бы моему боту после оплаты приходил конфиг с VDS сервера, конфиг именно на протоколе wire guard

Tags: sql, vds, wireguard

мне нужно что бы юзер заходил на моего бота (продажа впн конфигов) и покупал там подписку
на месяц- после оплаты что бы сервер а именно VDS сервер выдавал ему конфигурацию на месяц ( там есть прайс лист \месяц\3 месяца\ 6 месяцев \ 1 год\
как написать такой код ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Сам VDS отдать ничего не сможет, а вот ПО, установленное на нем, сможет. "Как написать такой код" - это в один ответ не влезет, учитывая, что вообще не понятно, что из перечисленного у вас не получилось, да и кода, собственно, нет. Для начала определитесь с языком программирования(на чистом SQL точно не получится)